# Two WKWebViews share local storage, but only after restart

Tags: ios, ios9, wkwebview

I have two `WKWebView`s `A` and `B` both loading local `file://`s. This is the behaviour I am seeing:

- In `A`, set `localStorage.setItem('test', true)`
- In `B`, read `localStorage.setItem('test')` which returns `undefined`
- Restart `B`
- In `B`, read `localStorage.setItem('test')` which returns `true`

So it seems that `A` and `B` share local storage, but do not sync in real time. This is very strange to me. Why isn't local storage synching between the two `WKWebView`s in real time?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to share a unique WKProcessPool between your WKWebView.

```
let uniqueProcessPool = WKProcessPool()

let configA = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configA.processPool = uniqueProcessPool
let webViewA = init(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configA)

let configB = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configB.processPool = uniqueProcessPool
let webViewB = init(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configB)
```

Without this, it will feel as if the WKWebView used a copy of a central ProcessPool instead of a reference access to it. Which explains why you don't see the changes in real-time and you need to reload your view.